# Make MDB wait/sleep for sometime programmatically

Tags: java, weblogic11g, ejb-2.x

We have a MDB process which read messages, process it and post it to another queue consumed by downstream xpression application.

Whenever heavy load is coming our way, this downstream application is not able to consume it at the rate in which we are posting, causing latency to its interfacing applications.

We need a solution to throttle message at our end. So the question here is how do you slowdown that rate at which MDB process consumes messages?

Our solution is to stop our MDB from consuming message from queue by invoking Thread.sleep(for some time) after reaching some threshold (which is safe for our downstream application).

But this design has its own flaw, what if thread is not getting resumed. How do you manage it?

Also is there any other better mechanism to handle this without even using thread.sleep()?

The application is on weblogic.

Comment: Have you looked at throttling mechanisms like Connection Factory Flow? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jmsconnectionfactory_config_flowcontrol.html This is much better than a sleep

Comment: Thanks for the direction, my application is sending message to MQ version less than 8. Below link gives details on how to delay in MQ8(JMS2.0) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119200_.htm I would like to know how we can achieve this in MQ 6 or 7